# How to merge if row in table exists

Tags: c#, linq, entity

I have a 3 tables joined in the statement below:

```
var data = from x in dbContext.Base_Agencies
                   from u in dbContext.Base_AgencyInstances
                   from o in dbContext.Payment2Account_SecurityRuleAgencies
                   where u.AgencyId == x.AgencyId
                   where o.AgencyId == x.AgencyId
                   where u.AgencyInstanceId == param.AgencyInstanceId
                   select new RsSecurityParamsResult
                   {
                       AgencyId = x.AgencyId,
                       AgencyNameView = u.AgencyNameView,
                       Stamp = u.Stamp,
                       Pni = x.Pni,
                       Prefix = u.Prefix,
                       ServiceEnabled = o.ServiceEnabled,
                       DisabledDateTime = o.DisabledDateTime,
                       AmountHourTresholdWarning = o.AmountHourTresholdWarning,
                       AmountHourTresholdStop = o.AmountHourTresholdStop,
                       CountHourTresholdWarning = o.CountHourTresholdWarning,
                       CountHourTresholdStop = o.CountHourTresholdStop
                   };
```

The problem is that in some examples there won't be a row for agency in table 'o'. In this situation I would like to select values only from other tables, except 'o' table. How should I do that?

Comment: what you mean by *there won't be a row for agency in table 'o'.*?

Comment: Situation when: 1. in table 'x' there is some row with some agencyId, 
2. in table 'u' there is a row with the same agencyId, 3. in the table 'o' there is no row with the same agencyId

Comment: yeah, you might want to check the answer posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` like

```
var data = from x in dbContext.Base_Agencies
                   join u in dbContext.Base_AgencyInstances 
                   on u.AgencyId == x.AgencyId
                   join o in dbContext.Payment2Account_SecurityRuleAgencies 
                   on o.AgencyId == x.AgencyId into lrs
                   from lr in lrs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new RsSecurityParamsResult
                   {
                       AgencyId = x.AgencyId,
                       AgencyNameView = u.AgencyNameView,
                       Stamp = u.Stamp,
                       Pni = x.Pni,
                       Prefix = u.Prefix,
                       ServiceEnabled =  lr.ServiceEnabled ?? "Default",
                        ...... // other code similar ........
                   };
```

Comment: there are couple of syntax mistakes in your answer but main idea is correct and it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution is:

```
  var data = from x in dbContext.Base_Agencies
                   join u in dbContext.Base_AgencyInstances
                   on  x.AgencyId equals u.AgencyId
                   join o in dbContext.Payment2Account_SecurityRuleAgencies
                   on x.AgencyId equals o.AgencyId into lrs
                   from lr in lrs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   where u.AgencyInstanceId == param.AgencyInstanceId

                   select new RsSecurityParamsResult
                   {
                       AgencyId = x.AgencyId,
                       AgencyNameView = u.AgencyNameView,
                       Stamp = u.Stamp,
                       Pni = x.Pni,
                       Prefix = u.Prefix,
                       ServiceEnabled = lr.ServiceEnabled,
                       DisabledDateTime = lr.DisabledDateTime,
                       AmountHourTresholdWarning = lr.AmountHourTresholdWarning ,
                       AmountHourTresholdStop = lr.AmountHourTresholdStop,
                       CountHourTresholdWarning = lr.CountHourTresholdWarning ,
                       CountHourTresholdStop = lr.CountHourTresholdStop
                   };
```